# How do I send data from my spring boot application to SOAP webservices?

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, wsdl, soapui

I have recieved a URL from Project B and I generated wsdl file from that url.
In the wsdl file, there are some fields for request and response.
Using wsdl2java i have generated java classes in my project.

Now my question is how do i send data in my Project A, to Project B? I am able to make an API and get data in json format. But I need to send this data to this Project B by hitting their URL. So how do I know what structure my request and response should be in? How do I hit their URL?
I dont understand how to start writing the code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You already have the URL (that is what you got the WSDL from). You already know the structure that is the classes you generated. Call the URL with a `WebServiceTemplate` from Spring WS and pass the filled request.

Comment: is it possible to share some articles or videos explaining this step by step? I dont understand how to read the wsdl file or the java files it generated. The files generated all have random names and random annotations i have never seen before.

Comment: Why would you need to read those java files? Just create an instance and send it.